# SVN repo within SVN repo?

Tags: wordpress, svn

I've set up a wordpress site using the information gleaned from http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Subversion and other such wordpress codex sites.

I noticed whilst setting this up that the askimet source is copied in from an external repository.

Is this easy to do? What I want is to have a separate repository for my site which imports other repos such as the Wordpress repo and any other repos I set up for custom plugins and all sorts.

In my repository I don't want to have the full Wordpress source, I would like to be able to link the Wordpress repo into it, so that when I `checkout` the trunk of **my** repo it also copies all of the Wordpress files.

So basically I'll have a structure like this:

1. Checkout/update all my custom files in my Wordpress repo
2. Checkout/update Wordpress from Wordpress SVN repo
3. Checkout/update any custom plugin repos I've added.

Some of the directories will be shared. For instance in the Wordpress repository's root I want to be able to have a file in my Site Repository (wp-config.php).

Can this be done, and if so how would I go about doing it?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the svn:externals property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `svn:externals` property. Each line in this property's value gives an URL and a directory; the SVN client will check out the repository at the URL into the named directory. Example:

```
$ svn propget svn:externals .
http://foo.bar/svn/repo wordpress
```

will produce a directory named wordpress in the current directory.

Comment: will this work with `http://foo.bar/svn/repo .` ? IE to checkout into the current directory?

Answer (score 1):

To add `svn:externals` property use `svn:propedit (pe)` or `svn propset (ps)` on the directory under which you want to checkout another branch.

E.g:

1. Checkout the base branch:

   ```
   $ svn co hxxp://wordpress/svn/repo/trunk siteroot
   ```
2. Edit the `svn:externals` property:

   ```
   $ svn pe svn:externals
   ```
3. Editor will be opened, where you can add one or multiple external branches/repositories:

   ```
   $ hxxp://wordpress/svn/repo/plugin wordpress_plugin
   $ hxxp://plugin2site/svn/repo/trunk another_plugin
   ```
4. Save and commit.

   ```
   $ svn ci
   ```
5. Finally you will get the following working copy structure:

   ```
   siteroot/
   siteroot/wordpress_plugin
   siteroot/another_plugin
   ```

You can also specify specific revision of the branch, so the external branch will be frozen to that revision (e.g. if you know it's stable). To do it, add `@REV` to the end of the URL:

```
$ hxxp://plugin2site/svn/repo/trunk@123 another_plugin
```

You can use `svn propset` instead of `svn propedit`, but be carefull, it will overwrite any existing data in the svn:externals property:

```
$ svn ps hxxp://plugin2site/svn/repo/trunk another_plugin .
```

For more info, see following chapter in the [SVN handbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html).

Comment: Thanks for the concise and descriptive answer. However, if I checkout (co) from the wordpress owned repo then the svn:externals property won't be saved against the repo, so I won't be able to checkout anywhere else with the same svn:externals. I need my own repository that I can commit to and have access to in order to use svn:externals. In this case can I use svn:externals to export the wordpress repo to my root folder? Thanks

Comment: @ThomasClayson , of course you can.  

E.g. you can create the following working copy structure:  
    `/root_repository/  
    /root_repository/wordpress  
    /root_repository/plugins`

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. In the wordpress repository there are sub directories e.g. `wp-content/plugins`. I want my SVN repo to look like this: `/root_repository/ (which ALSO draws from the wordpress repo)` `/root_repository/wp-content/plugins/ (a wordpress repo generated directory)` `/root-repository/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/ (from my external plugin repository)`.

Comment: I understand your need. Unfortunately, you can't put externals in the WordPress repository. The question if you really need it? Are you developing for WordPress and going to commit to it's trunk? Or you are using it for your own projects/sites? If you are using it for your own projects, you'll probably want to use some stable version and not trunk. Copy it to your own repository and then you'll be able to define externals inside it. To upgrade WordPress to newer version, you'll need to replace it's code and redefine externals, what is not such a big deal. You can write a script that does it.